# Is there a command that detects if the CD drawer is open or closed?

Tags: command-line, cd-drive

Is there a command that you can run in a shell script that would detect if the CD tray is open or closed, and return 1 or 0 depending on whether it was (or something easy to interpret)?

Currently, I am executing the open command, and timing how long it takes to execute. If it is almost instant, it is open. If it takes time, it was open and is now closed.

I would like a method that doesn't involve changing the current state - just detecting it.

Comment: Why do you need this? [There is probably a simpler way to achieve whatever your end goal is](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Do you just want to toggle the tray?

Comment: No, I do need to know if it is open as the aim is to be able to check, not togggle. I can toggle with `eject -T`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found a nice little solution [here](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/slackware-14/detect-cd-tray-status-4175450610/). The C code below, minimally changed from the linked site, will return an exit code of `0` if the tray is open and `1` if it is not.

So, save this code as something (e.g. `foo.c`) and compile it with this command:

```
gcc -o trayopen foo.c
```

Then, copy the compiled executable, `trayopen` to `/usr/bin`:

```
sudo cp trayopen /usr/bin
```

You should no be able to do things like

```
trayopen /dev/sr0 && echo closed
```

Or, more complete:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
if trayopen /dev/sr0
then
    echo "Tray is open."
else
    echo "Tray is closed."
fi
```

---

The code:

```C
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <linux/cdrom.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv) {
  int cdrom;
  int status=1;

  if (! argv[1] ){
    printf("Usage : trayopen [device]\n");
    printf("Result: Returns a 0 if the tray was open and 1 if it was closed\n");
    exit(2);
  }

  if ((cdrom = open(argv[1],O_RDONLY | O_NONBLOCK)) < 0) {
    printf("Unable to open device %s. Provide a device name (/dev/sr0, /dev/cdrom) as a parameter.\n",argv[1]);
    exit(2);
  }
  /* Check CD tray status */
  if (ioctl(cdrom,CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS) == CDS_TRAY_OPEN) {
    status=0;
  }

  close(cdrom);
  exit(status);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Based on @terdon's C code, I wrote a version in Python:

```py
#!/usr/bin/python
import os, fcntl, CDROM, sys

def drive_status(drive):
  fd = os.open(drive, os.O_RDONLY | os.O_NONBLOCK)
  rv = fcntl.ioctl(fd, CDROM.CDROM_DRIVE_STATUS)
  os.close(fd)
  return rv

sys.exit(drive_status(sys.argv[1]) != CDROM.CDS_TRAY_OPEN)
```

Clearly, it could use some love for comments and cmdline argument handling, but if you need a Python version... this will work.

Also note that the `CDROM` module may be Linux-specific, and that not all drives support querying (eg. the ioctl() will return `CDS_NO_INFO`).

There are other `CDROM.CDS_*` constants that provide helpful variants. In particular, `CDS_DISK_OK` will tell you if the tray is closed and has a disk present.

Comment: Note for [Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html?highlight=cdrom#api-and-feature-removals): "The undocumented `IN`, `CDROM`, `DLFCN`, `TYPES`, `CDIO`, and `STROPTS` modules have been removed. They had been available in the platform specific `Lib/plat-*/` directories, but were chronically out of date, inconsistently available across platforms, and unmaintained."

Comment: Thanks for the edit, and the Python 3.6 note, @muru ... if CDROM.py is not available, then the constants can be found at:
https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/uapi/linux/cdrom.h