# trigger script on open or close of cd drive

Tags: 18.04, input, cd-drive

I found several questions/answers about how to open/eject/mount a cd rom/drive. But I am after something else: **I would like to run a script whenever the cd drive either closes or opens**, it doesn't matter if there is a cd inside or not, nor if it is open or closed, basically I just need to connect a kind of event handler for the »down/up« event of the cd drive's button.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I've found so far is to constantly poll the drive for its status with ioctl. See [Is there a command that detects if the CD drawer is open or closed?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/483644/is-there-a-command-that-detects-if-the-cd-drawer-is-open-or-closed)
It's important to close and reopen the file descriptor on each poll; otherwise, you might not be able to mount the CD or DVD inserted.
YMMV, and I'm a newb, so there's probably a better way. On my RHEL 7 box with a USB DVD drive I see the drive status change to 2 (CDS_TRAY_OPEN) when the tray is opened and briefly to 3 (CDS_DRIVE_NOT_READY) when closed before changing to 1 (CDS_NO_DISC) or 4 (CDS_DISC_OK).

I had high hopes for udev, but with my drive I only saw events for adding or removing the drive or opening the tray when it contained a disc or closing the tray. I saw no event for opening an empty tray. You can try running `udevadm monitor` and see if you get events for opening or closing your tray. If so you can make udev rules to run your script when those events happen: https://opensource.com/article/18/11/udev
All my testing was on RHEL 7, so sorry if any of it is irrelevant for Ubuntu 18.04.